# Импорт mysql в excel

Tags: excel, mysql

Есть дамп бд mysql.Подскажите каким образом можно импортировать её в excell!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы импортировал дамп в БД, а потом сделал бы дамп в формате CSV, который легко читается excel.